# Google Maps - Validate Address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, validation, street-address

I'm trying to validate an address using Google Maps, and I realized that when the address could be wrong, the response has a partial_match. Is correct to reject the address if the json's response from geocode method has a **partial_match** attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider using an address verification service to check an addresses validity since Google Maps doesn't actually verify addresses https://smartystreets.com/articles/do-maps-verify-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google Maps documentation:

> partial_match indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact
>   match for the original request, though it was able to match part of
>   the requested address. You may wish to examine the original request
>   for misspellings and/or an incomplete address.

So yes, the return may be wrong, so probably it is not a good idea to take this response as a fully trusty one. Imagine that you've built a GPS app and you are sending people to the wrong address. It won't be good.